# print statement in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new with symfony and I'm looking for a a kind of "print statement". Before I was programming only with java so I could see and keep track of the code on my "console output" inside the IDE. Basically I was using  print system out

What could be the equivalent to symfony. For example

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->findOneById($id);
```

Could I do something like this:

echo $user, inside the controller? and see the result somewhere

Or I should allways render the $user:

```
return $this->render('FOSUserBundle::edit.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
```

then I could only see the result on the edit.html

Is that the only way? (using render)

Later on, I would like to use PHPUnit but at the moment I want to start from the basics

Thank you!

Comment: `var_dump($user->toArray());` should work.

Comment: Note that, when it comes to web applications, Java works differently than PHP. Anything you print to stdout will mix with the actual application output. If you want to see it in the console, I guess you can print to stderr (I've never tried), but PHP has step debuggers too.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? `echo $user` would only work if that was a primitive, or if the object implements `Stringable` or at least contains a `__toString()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
    public function fAction(Request $request){

    // ...

    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
          ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
          ->findOneById($id);

    var_dump($user); exit;

    // or ...
    exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user));

    // or if you've installed VarDumper component (see below):
    dump($user, $anotherUser, $request);
    exit;

    // ...

    }
```

Try installing [VarDumper](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component) component, and use its dump() function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I installed VarDumper and tried the dump function, but it didn't work. I Installed using the composer, and I added in my controller use Symfony\VarDumper; but the information is not displayed. In the AppKernel is registered under the "if" $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle(); But is not registered in the $bundles = array(

Comment: What version of Symfony have you installed? 2.6, 2.7, ... ? (Try with  php app/console -V )

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try adding exit; after dump(...) function

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to print a variable for debugging purposes in the middle of the script.
One of them is to use `var_dump()`.

Following code will dump your variable and terminate the script.

```
var_dump($users);
die();
```

Comment: I tried it, but I still have some questions. I added it inside the function, and the function is called every time I go to the route /list, the function renders to the html page list.html.twig Where wlll be displayed the result (var_dump($users) ? should I refresh the html page? Also, when I refresh the page (list.html.twig) my browser freezes and I can't do anything I need to restart the browser

Answer (score 0):

(assuming its a web app)
Symfony won't output your `echo` or `print` or `var_dump()` or `print_r()` or other such calls. Instead, it will go on to render your .twig file and output that. So if you want to see your debug output, you need to stop the symfony execution right after the output call, by calling `exit()`. And so the output will be visible in the browser. Like this:

```php
class SomeController extends AbstractController {
   public function someMethod(Request $request) {

      $user = $this->getDoctrine()
          ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
          ->findOneById($id);

      var_dump($user); // output
      exit(); // stop execution, now check your browser
    }
}
```

If you want to see the flow of your app without `exit`-ing, you [log it](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html)

```php
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class SomeController extends AbstractController {
   public function someMethod(Request $request, LoggerInterface $logger) {

      $user = $this->getDoctrine()
          ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
          ->findOneById($id);

      $logger->critical(print_r($user, true), [
          'context' => 'that is the user'
      ]);

      // ...keep going...

      $logger->critical('log something else');
   
      // ...keep going...
    }
}
```

Then you examine the logs, usually empty it, and run again if needed.

But really, to follow the flow of your web app, the best is a proper debugger with xDebug (it will take some tinkering to set it up but its well worth it).

Answer (score -1):

As mentionned in official documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#the-dump-function intead of php *var_dump* function, you can use :
`dump('my text: ', $myvar);`
and useful :
`dd('my text: ', $myvar);` *dump & die* to stop running after show infos

Also in twig code :

```
{{ dump( myvar ) }} // note that $ is removed
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Dear @NicoHaase, you was right so I completed… but did it justify -1 vote ?